# Is it possible to combine an Arrayformula with a Transpose?

Tags: filter, google-sheets-formula, sequence, array-formulas

How can I make the following google sheet calculation using "arrayformula"?

on C2:

```
=transpose(filter($B$2:$B,$A$2:$A=A2))
```

on C3:

```
=transpose(filter($B$2:$B,$A$2:$A=A3))
```

and so on.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZ4fb.png)

Thank you!

I wrote a formula for each cell to do it, but if new row added to the table, I need to copy the formula for each of them. That is why I need to use arrayformula for doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,torow(filter(B:B,A:A=Σ)))))
```